# Learning threading concepts 

Tags: python, c, multithreading

I have started threading in C and also Python recently and would like to know any good tutorials available for it.

Comment: What platform are you working on (Windows and Unix threading is quite different).

Comment: "treading in c and also python" !! Don't forget to wipe your feet before you come in the house...

Answer (score 2):

**C - Recommended Books**

Unix: [Butenhof, David R. - Programming with POSIX(R) Threads (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633922)

Windows: [Hart, Johnson M. - Windows System Programming (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321256190)

**Python - Online**

[Tutorial on Threads Programming with Python](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyThreads.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: +1 for Programming with POSIX threads. Also there is a good one by O'Reilly ... Pthreads Programming (Nichols, Buttlar, Farrell)

Answer (score 1):

You could write the threading yourself, it could be hard but doing that, you will learn more about threading.

Or you could use a preexisting threading library. It will let you implement threading faster in your application, but you may not learn as much as to what goes on "under the hood".

From your question, I cant see which path you want to take. For the latter, I suggest [boosts threading library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread.html). The other answers hold great links if you prefer the former path.

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found Interprocess [Communications in Linux: The Nooks and Crannies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130460427) to be extremely useful for IPC (and threading) in C.